# How to execute google script with python mass

Tags: python

I have link like this

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxx/exec?idcust=999&idmember=313&month=08&year=22

Then i want implementation this with Python. In python script i want read from file .txt.. how i can make mass checking with python file use in file.txt? the file.txt value is 999|313|08|22

Thank you!

Comment: URL seems to be broken...

Comment: I hide it becuase private. The output is JSON like this. `{"respons":"[{\"update_member_failed\":{\"fixable\":true,\"reason\":\"input_fail\"}}]"}` . Can you help me ?